# Does the Mountain Lion installer receive updates?

Tags: macos, install

I downloaded the Mountain Lion installer on the day it was released on the App Store. If I now wait some time before doing a clean reinstall:

- Does this installer receive updates?
- Is it updated only with 10.8.x releases, or is it independent of those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the installer is updated with 10.8.x releases as they come out. You will need to update the installer app through the App Store as you would for any other app. ( Source: [OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion: the Ars Technica review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/2/#purchase-and-installation)).

> Like any other application purchased from the Mac App Store, these OS
>   installers are updated in-place as part of the normal Mac App Store
>   update process when new versions are released. It's as if your Mac OS
>   X 10.6.0 installation disc gradually morphed into a 10.6.1 installer,
>   then a 10.6.2 installer, and so on.

Example given is 10.6, but the reviewer is talking about 10.8.